# Set field required in acumatica

Tags: acumatica

How do you set a field as required in Acumatica ERP?

Have tried making a customization and setting 'Required' as true and 'AllowNull' as false but that doesn't work.

Running version 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a field required, you must mark it with the [PXDefault] attribute inside the data access class.

Comment: adding the Required=true parameter in the attributes will put the asterick next to the field to give the visual queue only. As Gabriel said the [PXDefault] will require it.